# sum of Digits through Recursion

Tags: java, function, recursion, sum, digit

I am trying to make a recursive function which should return  the sum of digits. The function should have only one argument. So far I have this;

```
public int sumDigits(int n) {
    if(n%10 == n) // last digit remains
        return n;

    else{
        int rightdigit; 
        rightdigit = n%10; // taking out the right most digit
        return rightdigit + (n/10); // adding it to everything on left
    }
}
```

The function works for some values, specifically 2 digit numbers. But It gives out really odd values for some numbers like 730 which comes out to be 73 when it should be 10.

I have worked it out on paper but cant figure out where I am going wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: this does not recurse, it does not call itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't actually *recursing*. You've setup your base case, but when solving a problem recursively you should have code *within* the function that calls the function itself.

So you're missing a line that *calls* `sumDigits`, with a smaller argument.

Consider two important parts of a recursive soutlion:

1. The *base case*. This is the end of recursion, at which point your recursions will begin to return, in your case creating a sum.
2. The *recursion*: your recursive function will call itself, with a different argument, typically a smaller chunk of the problem.

Note that your problem fits this pretty well: you've got 2 cases in an if/else. Your base case is set up nicely, now in the other branch you'll want to actually recurse. It should be very obvious to you where to put the call to `sumDigits`.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is not recursive. It should call itself in the last part:

```
return rightdigit + sumDigits(n / 10);
```

This adds the right-most digit to the recursively summed number of the left-most digits.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a call to `sumDigits()`.
Change this line:

```
return rightdigit + (n / 10);
```

to this:

```
return rightdigit + sumDigits(n / 10);
```